# Xcode5 debugging on device - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, xcode5, breakpoints

I updated to new MacOS(Maverics) and to Xcode5. When i try to run and debug on device (ipad mini, iphone4 and 5), application starts and when I hit break point and click on step over or continue I get:
 `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code =1, address 0x0`.

It is quite strange because it happens on line where is: 
`NSLog(@"Something");`...

I tried to give my code to other colleagues and everything works without any problems ...

I tried to reinstall Xcode, reboot all devices and install all available updates - situation is still same.

Any tips on this? 
thanks

Edit:
I found that, Bad Access is problem only on older ios versions. IOS 7 devices are okay.

Comment: What lines of code are right before your NSLog? Or right after? Does it also crash if you remove your NSLog?

Comment: Well all we can tell you is what the error means.  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with `code 1` and `address 0x0` simply means "could not access memory", "invalid address 0x0", so an *NPE* by any other name.

Comment: Give us more code. And you can add Exception (On Throw) Breakpoint and maybe this show you some interesting things. Try it out.

Comment: Well the code is okay. I found that this problem has quite lot of people ... It is new bug in Xcode 5 ... :(

Comment: Try to enable Zoombies and run Instruments.. this will help to find the memory address at leads to crash :)

Comment: I've already tried this... I didn't get anything useful, I think, that new version of Xcode introduced new set of bugs... :(

Comment: This is definitely a bug in Xcode 5.0.1.   
See [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582957/exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x0-when-stepping-in-debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved with new version of xCode.