# How to downgrade Xcode 5.0.1 project to Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode5, downgrade, xcode5.0.1

I have upgraded to Xcode 5 but it has a debugging [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582957/exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x0-when-stepping-in-debugger/19732109#19732109) that makes it impossible to work.
My project was created in Xcode 4 but then I worked with it in Xcode 5

I installed Xcode 4.6.3
I opened my project in Xcode 4.6.3. 
I did:
 - Clean
 - Run

App compiled and apps runs on iPhone.

The problem is that at least one CPP file looks corrupted in Xcode 4 
If I open it in another editor then it looks Ok.

Maybe the project has some cache that I much clean.

Here is screenshot I made. I am still able to compile it without errors.
[image]

**PS**
I did the following trick. I removed the reference to the file from the project. I then created a copy of the file under a different name and added that new file to the project.

When I opened it in Xcode it looks corrupted.

If I open that new file in jEdit then it looks Ok.

I also tried fold/unfold.
I used folding with that file when was coding in Xcode 5

**PS2**

I have deleted `DerivedData` directory that I found in Xcode - Preference - Locations
Restarted Xcode and it does not help.

**PS3**

I can edit that file in jEdit and Xcode reloads file
I can edit file in Xcode and jEdit reloads it.

I added following 2 lines of code

// jedit line
// xcode line

jEdit shows correct CPP file
Xcode shows corrupted CPP file

It is still possible to compile and run it

**PS4**

Just got email from Apple that Xcode 5.0.2 GM seed is released.
It is not available in AppStore. I am downloading it now.

Comment: Try cleaning your derived data folder.

Comment: I deleted DerivedDat, restarted Xcode but it does not help.

Comment: Have you re-installed Xcode 5.0 in place of Xcode 5.0.1?

Comment: @Zaph No. I installed Xcode 4.6.3. Xcode 5 was installed from AppStore and I renamed it to Xcode5 then I downloaded Xcode4.6.3 and dragged it in Application directory.

Comment: Try Xcode 5.0.2 GM.  There have been fixes in the area of debugging.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks. I have updated questions with __PS4__ 1 hour ago that I am doing that. I will update question if it will work well or not

Answer (score 3):

When using a xib of storyboard from another version of Xcode:

1. Select the xib or storyboard.
2. In the "File Inspector" Under "Interface Builder Files" choose "Opens In…" and set it to be compatible with a previous version.  2.

Thx to @BJHomer for his comment which is included in part in this answer.
@Neal asked for someone to re-answer with this information because he was going to remove his answer and the comments would not be available.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read the bug is not in Xcode 5 and is limited to Xcode 5.0.1. Try deleting Xcode 5.0.1 and installing Xcode 5.

You should be able to go to the developer downloads page:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Find Xcode 5, download and install.

You will need to be a registered developer.

I don't see this link on the iOS developer site, only on the Mac developer site so it may not work for iOS only developers.

Reference: From the Apple forum 9121264:

> The problem indeed is 5.0.1 only. 5.0.0 is a hassle - doesn't support
>   "non-ios7 with arm64' deployment target

Comment: Thanks. Do you have references that Xcode 5.0 is bug free? I have not found any references that debugging bugs in Xcode 5.0.1 are not present in Xcode 5. I also had other minor bugs Xcode 5 (that forced me to clean project to often)

Comment: Added reference to the answer. Am I sure? No but it seems real.

Comment: Right. Thank You @Zaph Xcode 5 seems to be more stable. If there would be no solution with Xcode 463 and Xcode 5 will work few more hours then I will mark it as answer.